# ¿Como ejecuto JS en IMacros?

Tags: javascript, imacros

Tengo que darle click a un selector con Imacros, agregue esta linea

`URL GOTO=javascript:{document.body.children[3].children[0].children[9].click();}`
pero no funciona, al probar con document.body.children[3].children[0].children[9].click(); desde la consola de chrome funciona correctamente, pero desde IMacros no.

Comment: que rayos es `IMacros`?, vivo en otro planeta o debajo de una piedra y no me entero o es algo muy nuevo? xd.

Comment: te paso la web https://imacros.net/, no se si es nuevo pero para una necesidad actual me viene de lujo, el tema es que no logro ejecutar JS